# Impersonating an user in Linux through Java

Tags: java, linux, sudo, impersonation

I have a Java application that runs on a Linux server and performs series of actions (create directory, copies few files, checks if an application is running etc). I am using log4j2 for logging messages and it has been running fine.

I've a requirement to read an account and impersonate as that account (passwordless sudo switch user) and then perform series of above actions. Access to do a passwordless sudo has been taken.

I've already done this using a shell (first switch user and then execute the Java program) however I've raised this question to understand if this can be done within Java program ?

```
Execution:  java -jar xyz.jar parm1
```

To evaluate, I changed the Java code to run a shell command as below (I am using processbuilder):

When I run the Java program, the logs appear only till the point of sudo shell command execution and no logs are shown post that step.

Is there a way I can retain all logs before and after switching user (impersonating) ? (I'm using log4j2 and writing to a log file which has write access to other users).

Please share if there is any known solution ?

[EDIT] Adding java code snippet used to trigger sudo

```
public boolean switchUser(String account)  {

        ShellCommand shellCommand = new ShellCommand();

        List<String> cmd = new ArrayList<String>();
        cmd.add("su");
            //....I construct asu command for the passed account here. I have passwordless sudo su access and tested fine manually
        //I've some logger messages here
        shellCommand.runCommand(cmd);    //Class with method that uses ProcessBuilder and executes shell command        
    }
```

[EDIT] I think when I trigger su from Java it opens a new shell while Java is waiting for it to complete. This is possibly the reason of no logs visible there after. So one solution will be to Wrap it in a shell, do a su with command to run the jar.

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you. You see, maybe there is a bug in your code. How could we help with that without looking at relevant parts of your code?

Comment: You need to add the user you are switching to the [group](https://www.linode.com/docs/tools-reference/linux-users-and-groups/) which  have write access to the log file.

Comment: Hi @VictorGubin, I ensured that the switched account has write access on the log file but the logs inside stopped exactly at the same step where I am doing switching (su). Do you need any other information (code snippet etc) ?

Comment: What's `asu`? You keep saying "sudo" but you're calling "asu" which I'm not familiar with.

Comment: Hi @JohnKugelman, Please consider asu same as su (for security, companies restrict direct access on doing su and control it using a shell which is asu.sh. I've edited my question to su consistently) and Ive access to do a passwordless sudo on command "su". Problem I am facing is the moment su command is run, all further logs are not written. My log file has logs only until the "su" command is run.

Comment: I think when I trigger su from Java it opens a new shell while the Java is waiting for it to complete. This is possibly the reason of no logs visible there after.